# Python 3 State Trip Program: Code Registers Visiting The Same State As One Trip

Tags: python

I'm currently coding a State Trip code that documents what states you've visited in Python 3. If I input that I visited the state of Nj twice, my code registers this as only visiting Nj one time. I provided a picture and my entire code below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnIez.png)

CODE IS BELOW:

```
states = [ 'Nj', 'Fl', 'Ca', 'Ny', 'Ne', 
         'De', 'Ri', 'Ia', 'Or', 'Co']
ask = input("Do you want to start a trip?[Y/n]: ")
visited_states = []
i = 1
if (ask.lower() == "y"):
    print(states)
    startstate = input("From which state, you want to start? ")
    while startstate not in states:
        startstate = input("From which state, you want to start? ")
    visited_states.append(startstate)

    while i < 10:
        next_state = input("Enter next state: ")
        while next_state not in states:
            print("Please enter states from available states.")
            next_state = input("Enter next state: ")
        visited_states.append(next_state)
        visit_more = input("Do you want to visit more?[Y/n]: ")
        if visit_more.lower() != 'y':
            break
        i += 1
else:
    exit(0)

print("Visited States: ", end="")
count = 0
for i in visited_states:
    if i not in visited_states[:count]:
        print(i, end=" ")
        count += 1

print(f"\nTotal states visited are: {count}")
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `if` statement in your last `for` loop supposed to do?
Try removing it, it should print:

> Visited States: Nj Nj
> Total states visited are: 2